# Iframe (youtube) problem with padding-bottom

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I have to add a video from Youtube within certain limits (the red borders on screenshot). To add the video within these limits I need to use padding-bottom: 36%. Because of this you can't press the bottom block (with the date).

[image: Problem with padding-botton]

If I reduce this padding-bottom, the block with date moves to the right place but the height is reduced too.
Here is the part of css:

```
.calendar__general-slyde-video {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 36%;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 315px;
}
.calendar__general-slyde-video iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60%;
}
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: it seems like some irregularities with other css property's , can you provide bit more information.

Comment: I discribe here my problem. Maybe you can help me https://codepen.io/skaz_90/pen/NJLbjL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,if the link you provided is your code and your problem is to place the calendar just below the left most message , i.e `"calendar__changing-content" div`, then here are some of problems i found

first ,your `calendar__general-slyde-video clearfix` have `height:0` which means your video is being placed on the padding of the div.(which represents it's entire height)

second, your `"calendar__changing-content" div` does not contain it's children in a single row (assuming that's what you intended based on the given picture) hence your calendar is in the right place but it's sibling div's height is large which makes it appear distorted.

here is the solution to them:
add a height to the video and remove the padding also make the iframe `100%` height, also you can remove height from other children's if your wish.

```
.calendar__general-slyde-video {
 position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 315px;
height: 233px;
}

.calendar__general-slyde-video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

here is the [code pen](https://codepen.io/skaz_90/pen/NJLbjL)

this should solve your problem, also you can use `reset.css` to remove browser default settings (just suggesting)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your advice really helps me!

Comment: happy  to help :D